# Best gui implementation with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, user-interface, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am not an expert on Spring. I have used JSF components ice faces, prime faces etc. And also Asp.Net components DevExpress, Teleric, etc.

Of course GUI implementation of an app depends on needs of application but I need some advice.
Now I am creating jsp files by using jstl tags and jQuery. But I don't like this because jQuery is still has problems with different browsers. Sometimes I found myself debugging jQuery code instead of writing my own project and it takes a lot of time. I could not find much jsp tags helpful and useful. Any advice about that? I want to have some ready to use components such as gridviews, listboxes easy to use and not browser dependent.

Any advice would be helpful thank you.

Comment: "jquery is still has problems with different browsers" thats news to me, what problems ?

Comment: a lot of ajax requests with jquery ui components can turn your life into hell. works perfectly wiht chrome and firefox but on ie gives jquery dependent errors .to summarize it is not stable and nonstable site is not tolerable.

Comment: I am doing that - using jquery-ui with ajax, no problems at all. ie9 though, not tried it with ie6.

Comment: what should i do to convince you send my all app what do you want if you won't give a clue. Try using site mesh and jquery ui tabs with each tab maps to different controller and use ajax posts and gets see what happens.

Comment: It's not a JQuery problem, it's your code. An example can be if you forget a trailing comma in an array or object literal. Firefox will ignore that and IE will fail. If you code properly there won't be problems. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) can help you identify problem areas, even though is a little pedantic.

Comment: jQuery, being the most popular js framework, works consistently across browsers. You are misusing it somehow.

Comment: ok i was thinking like you untill i got these problems and ruin my week trying to find what is wrong try to find with firebug etc in jquery code my be my mistake i am not sure but it is too much effort for having a ajax based gridview i am asking for alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using spring-mvc + jQuery for the past 3 projects without any serious issue. So stick to jQuery. A few notes:

- get the latest jQuery version
- be careful with plugins - some plugins may have problems, but that's the same as JSF components having problems - it depends on their  vendor

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bozho, an alternative is [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/), which has higher quality controls than JQuery, however:

- **is not free** for commercial projects.
- the **learning curve** is quite steep, especially for version 3. I didn't try version 4 yet, they say is easier.
- it's a **heavier download**, more suited for an intranet, although you can also include only the components you need

On the plus side:

- works perfectly with **all browsers**, including IE 6
- the **quality** of the components is super